# Check it network drive is connected as a Windows service

Tags: c#, networking, directory, windows-services, mapped-drive

I'm using `Directory.Exists(<path>)` to check if a network/mapped drive is currently connected. I'm using the UNC Path which I get by reading the system's registry.

This works perfectly fine if I run my code through Visual Studio (it tells me that the directory does exist), but, it fails whenever I run the exact same code as a Windows service. I've checked the username and password of the service and it is the proper one needed - everything checks out.

I've also noticed that running Visual Studio as an admin return false while running as a normal user returns true. Does anyone have any idea as to what exactly is going on? I'm trying to get my program to behave the same whether I run it from Visual Studio or as a Windows service.

Comment: What are the details behind *"it fails"*

Comment: Are you getting an exception on the Windows Service or is it just returning false every time?

Comment: @Tronald It returns false every time as a service.

Answer (score 1):

Its obvious your service doesn't see the network drive,

- You need to run the *Service* under an *Account* that can see it, ie a *Domain User*, or a *User* with that share explicitly added
- Or you need to use the direct *IP Address* in the path (Providing its set up with the right *Permissions*) i.e `\\xxx.xxx.xx.xx\blah\blah`

***Note*** : in regards to the last option. Setting the Share Permissions is not enough. You will need to set the NTFS permissions appropriately